# SQL Query - Pivot with Ranges

Tags: oracle, query, pivot

This is my sample table

```
BSEG_ID DST_ID  BILL_SQ AUDIT_CALC_AMT  BILL_SQ, MSR_PEAK_QTY_SW, DESCR_ON_BILL, VERSION, AUDIT_CALC_AMT
12334   REV-WSC 62      6.40667         For 0 - 60 (Next 62.000 cubic meter) @US0.10 per cubic meter
12334   REV-WSC 62      64.06667        For 60 - 120 (Next 62.000 cubic meter) @US1.00 per cubic meter
12334   REV-WSC 3.6     11.16           For 120 - 180 (Next 3.600 cubic meter) @US3.00 per cubic meter
12334   REV_WWSC 62     3.20333         For 0 - 60 (Next 62.000 cubic meter) @US0.05 per cubic meter
12334   REV_WWSC 62     32.03333        For 60 - 120 (Next 62.000 cubic meter) @USSAR0.50 per cubic meter
12334   REV_WWSC 3.6    5.58            For 120 - 180 (Next 3.600 cubic meter) @US1.50 per cubic meter
11111   REV-WSC  62     6.40667         For 0 - 60 (Next 62.000 cubic meter) @US0.10 per cubic meter
11111   REV-WSC  62     64.06667        For 60 - 120 (Next 62.000 cubic meter) @US1.00 per cubic meter
11111   REV-WSC 3.6     11.16           For 120 - 180 (Next 3.600 cubic meter) @US3.00 per cubic meter
11111   REV_WWSC 62     3.20333         For 0 - 60 (Next 62.000 cubic meter) @US0.05 per cubic meter
11111   REV_WWSC 62     32.03333        For 60 - 120 (Next 62.000 cubic meter) @USSAR0.50 per cubic meter
11111   REV_WWSC 3.6    5.58            For 120 - 180 (Next 3.600 cubic meter) @US1.50 per cubic meter
```

Expected Output #1
**Range for Bill_SQ**

```
BSEG_ID DST_ID     0-10    10> <= 20    >20
11111   REV_WWSC    0          0         1
11111   REV-WSC     0          0         1
12334   REV_WWSC    0          0         1
12334   REV-WSC     0          0         1
```

Expected Output #2
**Range for Sum of AUDIT_CALC_AMT**

```
BSEG_ID DST_ID      0-10    10> <= 20   >20
11111   REV_WWSC    0         0          1
11111   REV-WSC     0         0          1
12334   REV_WWSC    0         0          1
12334   REV-WSC     0         0          1
```

This is my current query:

```
select a.bseg_id,a.dst_id, sum (a.bill_sq) as WaterConsumption ,sum (a.AUDIT_CALC_AMT) as SWConsumption from CI_BSEG_CALC_LN a 
--where a. BSEG_ID = '209875510608'
AND a.DST_ID in ('REV-WSC','REV-WWSC')
group by a.bseg_id, a.dst_id;
```

Please suggest a way for achieving the desired output.

This is what I have done so far

```
select * from ( select Bseg_ID , BILL_SQ, count (*) 
from CI_BSEG_CALC_LN 
where BILL_SQ Between '0' AND '5' 
--AND BILL_SQ Between '6' AND '10' 
--AND BILL_SQ Between '11' AND '15' 
--AND BILL_SQ Between '16' AND '20' 
--AND BILL_SQ > '20' 
group by Bseg_ID, BILL_SQ) PIVOT (Count (BSEG_ID) for BILL_SQ IN ('0-5'));
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Mysql** You can use SUM with an comparision, which returns 1 if the condition uis met or 0 if not.

> ```
> SELECT
>     `BSEG_ID`, `DST_ID`,
>     SUM(`BILL_SQ` BETWEEN 0 AND 10) '0-10',
>     SUM(`BILL_SQ` > 10 AND `BILL_SQ` <= 20) '10> <= 20',
>     SUM(`BILL_SQ` > 20) '>20'
> FROM CI_BSEG_CALC_LN
> GROUP BY `BSEG_ID`, `DST_ID`
> ```
>
> ```
> BSEG_ID | DST_ID   | 0-10 | 10> <= 20 | >20
> ------: | :------- | ---: | --------: | --:
>   11111 | REV-WSC  |    1 |         0 |   2
>   11111 | REV_WWSC |    1 |         0 |   2
>   12334 | REV-WSC  |    1 |         0 |   2
>   12334 | REV_WWSC |    1 |         0 |   2
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     `BSEG_ID`, `DST_ID`,
>     SUM(`res_sum` BETWEEN 0 AND 10) '0-10',
>     SUM(`res_sum` > 10 AND `res_sum` <= 20) '10> <= 20',
>     SUM(`res_sum` > 20) '>20'
> FROM
>     (SELECT
>          `BSEG_ID`, `DST_ID`,
>          SUM(`AUDIT_CALC_AMT`) res_sum
>      FROM CI_BSEG_CALC_LN
>      GROUP BY `BSEG_ID`, `DST_ID`) t1
> GROUP BY `BSEG_ID`, `DST_ID`
> ```
>
> ```
> BSEG_ID | DST_ID   | 0-10 | 10> <= 20 | >20
> ------: | :------- | ---: | --------: | --:
>   11111 | REV-WSC  |    0 |         0 |   1
>   11111 | REV_WWSC |    0 |         0 |   1
>   12334 | REV-WSC  |    0 |         0 |   1
>   12334 | REV_WWSC |    0 |         0 |   1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=506113482c9022390bcff3edea289cb8)*

**For ORACLE**

> ```
> SELECT
>     BSEG_ID,DST_ID,
>      SUM(CASE WHEN BILL_SQ >= 0 AND BILL_SQ <= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "0-10",
>      SUM(CASE WHEN BILL_SQ > 10 AND BILL_SQ <= 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "10> <= 20",
>     SUM(CASE WHEN BILL_SQ > 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ">20"
>     
> FROM CI_BSEG_CALC_LN
> GROUP BY BSEG_ID, DST_ID
> ```
>
> ```
> BSEG_ID | DST_ID   | 0-10 | 10> <= 20 | >20
> ------: | :------- | ---: | --------: | --:
>   12334 | REV-WSC  |    1 |         0 |   2
>   12334 | REV_WWSC |    1 |         0 |   2
>   11111 | REV_WWSC |    1 |         0 |   2
>   11111 | REV-WSC  |    1 |         0 |   2
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     BSEG_ID,DST_ID,
>      SUM(CASE WHEN res_sum >= 0 AND res_sum <= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "0-10",
>      SUM(CASE WHEN res_sum > 10 AND res_sum <= 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "10> <= 20",
>     SUM(CASE WHEN res_sum > 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ">20"
> FROM
>     (SELECT
>          BSEG_ID,DST_ID,
>          SUM(AUDIT_CALC_AMT) res_sum
>      FROM CI_BSEG_CALC_LN
>      GROUP BY BSEG_ID, DST_ID) t1
> GROUP BY BSEG_ID, DST_ID
> ```
>
> ```
> BSEG_ID | DST_ID   | 0-10 | 10> <= 20 | >20
> ------: | :------- | ---: | --------: | --:
>   12334 | REV-WSC  |    0 |         0 |   1
>   12334 | REV_WWSC |    0 |         0 |   1
>   11111 | REV_WWSC |    0 |         0 |   1
>   11111 | REV-WSC  |    0 |         0 |   1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7c01a20c33915e4ef245bd43503633a2)*

Comment: thanks nbk. However, have slightly tailored your query as it is giving error on PLSQL.SELECT
    BSEG_ID, DST_ID,
    SUM(BILL_SQ BETWEEN 0 AND 10) "0-10",
    SUM(BILL_SQ > 10 AND `BILL_SQ` <= 20) "10> <= 20",
    SUM(BILL_SQ > 20) ">20"
FROM CI_BSEG_CALC_LN
GROUP BY BSEG_ID, DST_ID;                                                                                                                  this is slightly tailored query but still i ma getting following error  "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"

Comment: you should have tagged the question with oracle and version you used.

Comment: Apologies ..i am using plsql developer 4.1

Comment: @Nabeel i added an Oracle Version, it is basically the same, only without shortccuts